# Android: Display received data from a foreground service onto a MapView inside an activity

Tags: android, google-polyline

I've implemented a `foreground service` for giving me the current location every 10 seconds. With the collected data I want to display a route on the map.

However, when dealing with location tracking and services, the screen of the phone won't be always on, because of battery saving. So the activity will call `onPause()`, `onStop()` methods and the earliest point for the `MapView` update will be after `onResume()`. Up to this moment on every broadcast to the activity I send the list of all `LatLng` objects, clear the route up to this moment and display again the route using a `Polyline`

It does the job, but somehow I find it very inefficient, speaking of system resources.

Alternative will be on every broadcast to save the received LatLng objects in a list like `List<LatLng> points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();`  initialized in the activity, and for displaying the data, computethe difference between the received coordinates and those who are already saved in the Activity's List, and display only those to the `Polyline`.

What do you think? Is there also a better approach than these two?

Comment: Where is the question exactly?

Comment: Whether there is also a third alternative in terms of system resources, better than these two?

Comment: how many points are you trying to keep track of ? how long will the foreground service be running for ?

Comment: Depending on the user. If he doesn't stop the service within 2 hours, then 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, i have to mention stackoverflow is about a question regarding code optimizations, bugs, software problems and solutions not ideas.

A foreground service every 10 seconds will be expensive regarding CPU and battery.  With that being said, there are a few ways you can go around this:

```
// Store data in somekind of database
1- SQLite (On the phone not recommended as writing and reading database values can take alot of time and be resource-extensive)
2- Firebase(Remote best option)
3- SharedPrefernces(On the phone but single key-value pairs works for your case )
```

Firebase tutorial : https://www.androidauthority.com/create-a-gps-tracking-application-with-firebase-realtime-databse-844343/

```
//To minimize resource usages instead of a foreground service consider but try to increase your time between requests.
1-AlarmManger
2-setWindow
3-setExact
```

Finally, please do not remove your old `polyline` and create a new one as graphics are memory and battery enemy. just do something like:

```
LatLng somePoint = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

//Then add this point to the existing `polyline`:

List<LatLng> fullPointList = somePolyLine.getPoints();
fullPointList.add(somePoint);
somePolyLine.setPoints(fullPointList);
```

Comment: My bad about the idea, I'm relative new to the Android development and for some cases I'm not sure what exactly to use. You mentioned SharedPreferences, but under "value" you mean only one coordinate and not list of them?

Comment: Let me introduce you to your new best friend android documentation : https://developer.android.com/docs

 Search or navigate  to SharedPreferences and check them out. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you (:

Answer (score 0):

Set the unique id for your current route. When the service is running, store the points to the DB. Then broadcast your event (may be with your current route id) and load them separately from your Activity to get the points.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, so instead of using data structures, better to use a DB?

Comment: Yes, thus you don't need to store them when the Activity state changed.

Comment: Okay, but how you're going to update the map? I mean, the service is running, we save the data to the DB. After the activity's onResume() is called, we will get the data from the DB, but after the service has stored in the same time another coordinate, it will be not displayed in the Map. So it will works only if we turn off and turn on the screen, but in the case when the screen is continuously turned on.

Comment: Your service does two tasks each time it receives a location update, store the latest point to the db and broadcast the event. The activity should observes that broadcast.

Comment: if you are talking about SQLite or some sort of in-house (on the phone) database, please dont. it will be worse than what you currently have.

Comment: However if you are talking about some kind of remote database Deployd, Firebase then you are 100% right.